# It is not what it's called

Tags: riddle

> My color like coal,  or being in a hole.
>
> My skin is hardcore, a steely abode.
>
> When things turn sore, me you procure.
>
> 'Cause I remember why the dismember.
>
> I have orange hue, you were tricked, too.

---

Disclaimer: Pardon one of the stanzas for being  violent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you:

> A flight recorder, AKA Black Box

My color like coal, or being in a hole.

> Black as coal, at least in name

My skin is hardcore, a steely abode.

> A flight recorder is encased in a hard, steel box.

When things turn sore, me you procure.

> In a flight disaster, the black box is searched for...

'Cause I remember why the dismember.

> ...because it records (remembers) what has happened

I have orange hue, you were tricked, too.

> Despite the nickname, a "black" box is actually orange - which also explains the title "It is not what it's called" - a black box, is in fact not a black box.